# Why is this "If-Else if- else" statement not working for the process.start?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am struggling to see why this if-Else if- Else statement is not working.

```
string JPRO_8_5_0 = @"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{0809190b-37e7-4852-9f0c-e183636739ba}\JproSetup.exe";
string JPRO_8_4_0 = @"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{270ce95e-5e84-4b6a-8d58-f8905b0a3cfc}\JproSetup.exe";


if (JPRO_8_5_0 != null)
{
    Process a = new Process();
    a.StartInfo.FileName = JPRO_8_5_0;
    a.StartInfo.Arguments = "/uninstall /quiet";
    a.Start();
}
else if (JPRO_8_4_0 != null)
{
    Process b = new Process();
    b.StartInfo.FileName = JPRO_8_4_0;
    b.StartInfo.Arguments = "/uninstall /quiet";
    b.Start();
}
else
{

}
```

So basically what I am needing to do is have the program check the files listed in the strings, and if it is there, run the silent installer.

I know the first silent installer will go through if I have that file installed. However, I need it to check for multiple versions as we have around 20 different versions out there I need to be able to remove at any point.

When it goes to check, if the JPRO_8_5_0 is not there, it will panic and say the item is not found (yeah, no duh). I want this to skip whatever versions are not found and move onto the next version to check.

Any advice on why this is not working for me?

Comment: Because you are setting the string values in the previous lines, neither of them will be null. Therefore your first `if` statement will execute. But if the file doesn't exist, then you will get an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Hope this helps you.

```
    using System.IO;

string JPRO_8_5_0 = @"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{0809190b-37e7-4852-9f0c-e183636739ba}\JproSetup.exe";
string JPRO_8_4_0 = @"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{270ce95e-5e84-4b6a-8d58-f8905b0a3cfc}\JproSetup.exe";

try {

if (File.Exists(JPRO_8_5_0))
{
    Process a = new Process();
    a.StartInfo.FileName = JPRO_8_5_0;
    a.StartInfo.Arguments = "/uninstall /quiet";
    a.Start();
    MessageBox.Show("JPRO_8_5_0 Exists.");
}
if (File.Exists(JPRO_8_4_0))
{
    Process b = new Process();
    b.StartInfo.FileName = JPRO_8_4_0;
    b.StartInfo.Arguments = "/uninstall /quiet";
    b.Start();
    MessageBox.Show("JPRO_8_4_0 Exists.");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("File Does Not Exists.");
}

}
catch { }
```

Comment: I will try this and let you know. This is my first major program I am working on since school so I'm still getting the hang of it since school doesn't teach you all this haha

Comment: You are amazing for laying it out, I was having a massive brain fart. This worked!

Comment: @AnnaCollins alright , it will work. also you do not really need to declare 20 strings for each version and set their path as their value what you can do is just replace the JPRO_8_5_0 with the filepath itself. Just like this - File.Exists(@"Path"). Also i have updated the code and added try and catch exception therefor whenever an exception is thrown for a file version it will skip that and check the next as you mentioned. I Would suggest you to read this for more information on exception handling : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/

Comment: Note that the `else` is only for the last `if`, i.e. if the last file doesn't exist it will print that the file doesn't exist, even if the first one exists.

Comment: Yes i forgot to mention as @Magnetron said if you want to show a messagebox for each file if it is not found you will need to add else {  //code  } for each if.

Comment: I am trying to make the program itself easy as possible for our customers so once they hit the run button it will execute then say "Program removed". So I am leaving the last Else statement empty so that no extra message occurs. Thank you for the advice though.

Answer (score 7):

Your "if/else" doesn't check if the file is there, it only checks that the string is not null (which, according to your code, it never is).

You need to modify the code to check if the file exists. See [File.Exists(path)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_IO_File_Exists_System_String_).

Answer (score -2):

You do not need else part.

```
    if (JPRO_8_5_0 != null)
    {
        Process a = new Process();
        a.StartInfo.FileName = JPRO_8_5_0;
        a.StartInfo.Arguments = "/uninstall /quiet";
        a.Start();
    }
    if (JPRO_8_4_0 != null)
    {
        Process b = new Process();
        b.StartInfo.FileName = JPRO_8_4_0;
        b.StartInfo.Arguments = "/uninstall /quiet";
        b.Start();
    }
```

Comment: The issue here is that he's checking if the strings are null rather than checking if the file specified by the string exits.

Comment: Removing the "else" does nothing to improve the code.  It will still fail if the file doesn't exist.